# Follow to the redirect links in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How i can set this? i have written handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302, 303], but scrapy does not follow to the new links, it just has begun to save empty files of pages.

P.S. English is not my native language. Exuse me for that.

Answer (score 7):

Scrapy does handle redirects by default, meaning that the [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect) is activated in the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` setting and the `REDIRECT_ENABLED` setting is set to `True`.

Answer (score 6):

You will also need to mention `dont_redirect = true` in your request as:

```
meta = {'dont_redirect': True, "handle_httpstatus_list" : [301, 302, 303]}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this was just what I was looking for. Adding the "handle_httpstatus_list" to individual requests was what did the trick.